# How to make variable from the value returned by a getTextWidth method?

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on a barchart for a school assignement. However I got stuck when trying to position the bar label at the left of the bar. I assume I have to use a method to get the width of the label text and then substract the value from the x position of the bar.

```
public class Bar {
    // the numeric value of the bar
    private int value;
    // the rectangle representing the bar
    private Rectangle view;
    // The text label for this bar
    private Text label;
    // The value as a text object
    private Text valueText;

    /**
     * Constructor for a bar object.  The rectangle for the bar is
     * also constructed here and its size is set to the given height.
     * The value of the bar is initialised to 0.
     * If there is a label for the bar, a Text object is created using the 
     * text of the label and the colour of the label set to black.
     * The bar and the label are not visible until the display method
     * is called.
     *
     * @param label The label for the bar.
     * @param width The height of the bar.
     */
    public Bar(String label, int height) {

        view = new Rectangle();
        view.changeSize (0,height);
        this.label = new Text(label);
        display();
    }

    public  void display() {
        label.makeVisible();
        view.makeVisible();
    }

    public void setValue (int Newvalue){
        value= Newvalue;
    }

    public void setPosition (int x, int y){
       view.setPosition(x,y);
       label.setPosition(x,y);
    }

    public int getTextWidth() {
        return (int) ((Text)label).getWidth();

    }
}
```

Edit:
I have attached a screenshot of of my BlueJ program so far and also the assignment description.
[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Skwo.png)
[assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVAbS.png)
I have created in the Public calss bar, a bar as a Rectangle named "view". The rectangle's (bar) width is initially set to zero, that is why on canvas appears as a line (see picture). I have created a label as Text, which must appear to the left of the bar( my rectangle) everytime I edit is width. The point is I don't know how to edit is width in the method Public void set value. When I call the method and I enter 100 as the parameter value, the value of the bar should change to 100 and the width of the view (rectangle) should change to 100 but it dosen't. And the label is in the wrong position. In the setPosition method I have to make the label appear to the left of the rectangle(bar). But how? And then when I call the display method I must see on the cavas the value representing the bar width. How? Many thanks.

Just so you know, I am an absolut beginner, only 3 weeks into my course.

So basically I want the value returned by getTextWidth() to substract it from the x coordinate of the bar (the text must appear at the left of the bar). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is a class representing an object. Give us a reference of what you have implemented to achieve the subtraction that you mentioned about

Comment: getWidth() is not a function of type Text. may be you need to get the width of a label(a gui object) where you would place a text in it and then subtract it with x coordinate.